# Searching Scala array to find a value and mapping it to (Array without the Value,Value)

Tags: arrays, scala, arraybuffer

I have a scala Array of the form :

```
temp: Array[(Array[String], Long)] 
# Eg.  Array((Array(attr1,1.0,attr2),15),(Array(1.0,attr5),15),(Array(attr3,attr4,0.0),15),(Array(attr3,attr4),5))
```

I need to take this Array and map it to something like

```
temp: Array[(Array[String],String, Long)] 
# Eg.  Array((Array(attr1,attr2),1.0,15),(Array(attr5),1.0,15),(Array(attr3,attr4),0.0,15),(Array(attr3,attr4),NULL,15))
```

I am searching for the string 1.0 and 0.0 and making a new array with 1.0 and 0.0 deleted from the original. Incase 1.0 and 0.0 not present then use NULL as the value. 
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What's the proper procedure if there is more than one "0.0" or "1.0"?

Comment: there won't be any duplicates the array has unique values for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the elements of a collection from one type to another type? Sounds like a `map`.

```
temp.map{ case (ss,l) =>
  ( ss.filterNot(_ matches "[01]\\.0")
  , ss.find(_ matches "[01]\\.0").getOrElse("NULL")
  , l )
}  // res0: Array[(Array[String], String, Long)]
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything I am getting this error: <console>:3: error: illegal start of simple expression

Comment: No import needed. This code only assumes that a `val` named `temp` exists and it is of type `Array[(Array[String], Long)]`.

Comment: I was using () instead of {}. Brilliant. How did you know about the filterNot function. Is there some guide to reach to such cool functions?

Comment: I keep a tab to the [Scala Standard Library](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/) open and available at all times. Sometimes I just wander through the pages just to see what new things I can find.